# Guice: When to kick off injection/bootstrapping in a headless JAR?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jar, guice

So I'm writing a bunch of components (that will be packaged as JARs), and they are all using Guice for DI. These components are just reusable, "commons"-type JARs that will be used by other downstream projects.

My understanding with Guice is that you implement a concrete `Module` and use that to bind objects together and, in effect, configure all of your DI. It is also my understanding that you should then have a single "bootstrapping" phase where the Guice injector is created, and then all dependencies the module is configured with are then fetched from that injector with `injector.getInstance(SomeClass.class)`.

That would work great in standalone application, that had some entry point, where you could invoke an `init()`-style method to then bootstrap Guice with, but in a headless JAR that has no entry point, I'm struggling with trying to determine when/where/how to bootstrap Guice.

These will be JARs living on the classpath and, at any point in time, an external entity could invoke and class and any method inside of them. I thought about using up a "lazy initialization" set up, where a method checks to see if its dependencies have been configured yet, and, if so, kicks off a bootstrap method.

But that's a really terrible solution! Partly, because that would require every class to have its own `Module` (which is ridiculous), and it would also pollute my entire codebase with DI-related code.

I'm clearly missing some Guice fundamentals here, otherwise I don't see how Guice could be used in anything other than an app where execution from start to finished is known and controlled. Any code samples are a huge plus! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

If other code wants to configure your classes *without* using Guice, it should be able to. However, you should provide a Guice module which binds everything in a reasonable way so that other code (perhaps other modules) can install your module, and then inject the dependencies into their own classes.

Of course, you don't need to expose a module yourself at all - you can leave it up to others to perform all the binding. However, you *may* wish to provide a module to avoid exposing your implementation details - you can expose a public interface and a public module, but then keep the implementation package-private. The module can bind the interface to the implementation without the caller knowing anything about it.

You may also want to investigate *private modules*, so that you can bind dependencies that *your code* needs, without exposing them more widely.

Something, somewhere is going to have to create an injector - but if your code is just "library" code, then it almost *certainly* shouldn't be you. You shouldn't be performing the injection yourself - you should just be making your code *amenable* to injection.

Comment: +1, although beware that with Guice private modules are pretty much completely broken (if you use guice-multibinder or guice-servlet for example, private modules do not work at all due to known bugs)

Comment: Interesting philosophy, and I'm not at all opposed to adopting it, save for one hangup. Imagine a scenario where the library has 2 components, `A` and `B`, and `B` depends on `A`. Now a downstream project uses them both. With my approach `A` and `B` configure themselves, and so this 3rd component that uses both (`C`) doesn't worry about config. With your approach though, `C` would need to configure `A` for iself **and for** `B` as well. E.g., `A` has a logging component that allows you to specify which component the log statements are coming from - you need 2 log configurations.

Comment: @AdamTannon: Your approach falls down if A and B don't have enough information to configure themselves on their own, of course. With my approach, C could either configure A once and use the *same* bindings for itself and B, or it could use different ones - it's nice and flexible.

Comment: @Steven Schlansker: Which known bugs are you referring to?